# How to add accessibility icon to screen reader like JAWS, Voice over and Talkback?

Tags: javascript, angular, accessibility, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader

I get an assignment that want me to update the privacy page content. there is a heart icon on one of the key values in the content json file. this needs to be read by all the screen reader applications like JAWS, Voice over and talk back

this is how I approach the problem.

I added span to the json file  `span <span class="sr-only">heart</span>`

And then added class in the to the  css :

```
.sr-only {
    position:absolute;
    left:-10000px;
    top:auto;
    width:1px;
    height:1px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**expected Behaviour**
Icon should be read by  screen reader like JAWS, Voice over and Talkback

**Actual behaviour**
it is only read by NVDA

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I suggest all new users visit [ask[ for tips on asking a question in a manner that best enables the community to provide you with helpful direction.  For this question, I am unclear what it is you are asking.  What do you mean you want to "add [an] accessibility icon to screen reader"?  It seems like you want to add some sort of heart icon, but I'm unclear how this relates to accessibility nor what problem it is you are facing.  Please clearly explain your problem, the steps to reproduce, the expected behavior, and the actual behavior, plus a [mcve].  Good luck, happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

The heart icon usually means you want to mark an item a "favorite".  You don't have to literally use text that describes the *shape* of the icon.  Instead, you should use text that describes the *purpose* of the icon.  In this case, something like "mark as favorite".

Most heart icons are also interactive.  You can click on them with a mouse and it changes the heart icon from an empty/outline shape to a filled shape.  The icon must be keyboard focusable (using the <kbd>tab</kbd> key) and selectable (<kbd>space</kbd> or <kbd>enter</kbd>).  That's typically done by making the icon a real `<button>`.

If you use the `<button>` element with a nested `<img>` for the icon, then specify an `alt` attribute for the `<img>` that says "mark as favorite".  You'd have something like this:

```html
<button>
   <img src="heart.jpg" alt="mark as favorite">
</button>
```

To be complete, you'd probably have a different image when the heart is selected so you'd want the `alt` text to indicate that selecting the heart again will clear the item as a favorite.

```html
<button>
   <img src="filledheart.jpg" alt="clear as favorite">
</button>
```

A second solution is to use [`aria-pressed`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-pressed) to have a toggle button.  You'd toggle the attribute value between true/false (and toggle the icon between empty and filled).

A third solution is to make the heart a checkbox.  The heart is essentially checked or unchecked (filled or empty) so a checkbox/switch fits the paradigm.

Comment: Thanks @Sluglicious for the effort to give a help, but this is not what I want achieve.

Comment: I went on the limited info in your question.  Please explain better what you want.